# Postgresql: Dynamic Regex Pattern

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I have event data that looks like this:

```
 id | instance_id | value
 1  | 1           | a
 2  | 1           | ap
 3  | 1           | app
 4  | 1           | appl
 5  | 2           | b
 6  | 2           | bo
 7  | 1           | apple
 8  | 2           | boa
 9  | 2           | boat
10  | 2           | boa
11  | 1           | appl
12  | 1           | apply
```

Basically, each row is a user typing a new letter. They can also delete letters.

I'd like to create a dataset that looks like this, let's call it `data`

```
 id | instance_id | value
 7  | 1           | apple
 9  | 2           | boat
12  | 1           | apply
```

My goal is to extract all the complete words in each instance, accounting for deletion as well - so it's not sufficient to just get the longest word or the most recently typed.

To do so, I was planning to do a regex operation like so:

```
select * from data
where not exists (select * from data d2 where d2.value ~ (d.value || '.'))
```

Effectively I'm trying to build a dynamic regex that adds matches one character more than is present, and is specific to the row it's matching against.

The code above doesn't seem to work. In Python, I can "compile" a regex pattern before I use it. What is the equivalent in PostgreSQL to dynamically build a pattern?

Comment: How do you know what a word is?  I mean, why isn't "boa" and "a" and "app" in your list?

Comment: Sounds more like you want to compare all values against a dictionary. I cannot imagine how regular expressions should help here (at least to do the job completely on their own).

Comment: Hey guys - actually not interested in dictionary words at all (our actual data isn't dictionary words anyway). We see two triangular patterns, I'm interested in the "peaks" ie: a > aa > aaa > aaaa > aaa > aa > aab has two peaks: aaaa and aab.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=86a311beea2bb96644400d597619433e

Comment: Abelisto, can you share that as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Try simple LIKE operator instead of regex patterns:

```
SELECT * FROM data d1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM data d2
  WHERE d2.value LIKE d1.value ||'_%'
)
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=cd064c92565639576ff456dbe0cd5f39

Create an index on `value` column, this should speed up the query a bit.

Comment: This worked for my base case, thank you! Is there a way to build a dynamic pattern though?

Answer (score 1):

To find peaks in the sequential data [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) is a good choice. You just need to compare each value with previous and next ones using [`lag()` and `lead()` functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW-TABLE):

```
with cte as (
  select 
    *, 
    length(value) > coalesce(length(lead(value) over (partition by instance_id order by id)),0) and
    length(value) > coalesce(length(lag(value) over (partition by instance_id order by id)),length(value)) as is_peak
  from data)
select * from cte where is_peak order by id;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=86a311beea2bb96644400d597619433e)